# Kendo grid value not changing while adding new record to grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Actually, I want to do the calculation. While Editing the existing record Amount calculating and updating well, but while adding new value to the grid then it's not working. Please have look my example then will get my issue. http://dojo.telerik.com/Uyedu

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle `save` event, not `edit`:

```
dataSource: {
    ...
    save: function(e) {
        e.model.Amount = e.model.Quantity * e.model.Rate;
    }
}
```